# Right Align an Element in CSS While Maintaining Document Flow

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to right align an element in CSS without removing it from the document flow?

For instance,

```
position:absolute;
right:0;
```

would right align the element, but the element would be removed from the document flow. Likewise, `float:right;` would also mess with layout. Is it possible to right align an element with `position:relative`? Or is there some other way of right aligning elements easily?

I'm asking because I need to use `right:` to set the position of the element on certain JavaScript events, but I also need it to take up space so that elements underneath it don't all need to be manually positioned by hand.

Answer (score 4):

Apply `display: inline-block;` to it and wrap it with another element with `text-align: right;` on it.

```css
.right-container {
  text-align: right;
}

.align-right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-container"><div class="align-right"></div></div>
<div class="some-text">Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text</div>
```